# Will calling the same API inside both generateMetadata and the main component result in Next.js 13 making the API call twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to generate metadata based blog data from the API

`src/app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx`

```js
export async function generateMetadata(props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const blog = await fetch(`https://my-api.com/blog/${props.params?.slug}`).then((res) => res.json())

  return {
    title: blog.title,
    description: blog.meta_description,
    keywords: blog.meta_keywords
  }
}

export default function Page({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  const blog = await fetch(`https://my-api.com/blog/${params?.slug}`).then((res) => res.json())

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: blog?.content || '',
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

does code above calling the api twice? Because I can't find documentation to pass fetched data to generateMetadata using props in Next.js 13

Comment: im also using same approach to generate metadata dynamically, code works fine in development, but I'm encountering an error when trying to build the app. any thoughts?

Type error: Type 'ResolvingMetadata | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'ResolvingMetadata'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ResolvedMetadata>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if the function you're calling is internally calling fetch it is automatically deduplicated by Next.js as can be read in the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping).

---

Should you be directly calling a database or using a fetch alternative (like axios) as explained you can use Reacts new `cache()` function to deduplicate calls to logic that does not automatically get deduped by Next.js. More can be found in the official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping)

```
import { cache } from 'react'
 
export const getPerson = cache(async () => {
   // your logic ...
});
```

Although the `getPerson()` function is called twice, inside the page and metadata generator, only one call will be made. This is because the function is wrapped in `cache()`, so the second request can reuse the result from the first request.